# create flow run on localhost with http request: How to pass parameters? GRAPHQL_PARSE_FAILED

Tags: graphql, prefect

I want to start a flow run with a post request.

```sh
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"query": "{ flow{id} }"}' \
http://localhost:4200/graphql
```

Above is basic interection with api.

**The mutation query:**

```
mutation {
  create_flow_run(
    input: {flow_id: "cabfecfb-8ce7-47aa-9ba4-c181dbf4a430", 
            parameters: "{ \"points_y_column\": \"lat\", \"points_x_column\": \"lon\", \"out_format\": \"CSV\"}"}
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

This query works on Graphq interface. Quotes in **parameters** prefixed with "\".

How I can fit query into string. Like:

```sh
-d '{"query": "<my_mutation_query>"}'
```

**Python approach**

```py
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
            'tenant_id': 'f874d20a-ba21-4c7f-1111-d43cbf4751e9'}

query = """mutation {
  create_flow_run(
    input: {flow_id: "cabfecfb-8ce7-47aa-9ba4-c181dbf4a430", 
            parameters: "{ \"points_y_column\": \"lat\", \"points_x_column\": \"lon\", \"out_format\": \"CSV\"}"}
  ) {
    id
  }
}"""
r = requests.post(req_url , json = {"query": query}, headers=headers)
```

I get the following error:
`b'{"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error: Expected :, found String \\": \\"","locations":[{"line":4,"column":44}],"extensions":{"code":"GRAPHQL_PARSE_FAILED"}}]}\n'`

Comment: just use variables ... https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables ... check request body details from playground test or use search

Answer (score 0):

I just push everything into variables dictionary and encode at the last stage. My mistake is to bury the encoded json as string into dictionary.

```py
url = 'http://localhost:4200/'   
query = '''
mutation ($flow_id: UUID! , $parameters: JSON!) {
  create_flow_run(input : { flow_id: $flow_id,  parameters: $parameters}) {
    id
  }
}
'''
json_params = { "random_array_lenght": 5}
flow_id = "eb8e2f91-bfef-487d-bde1-741bdcb6256c"
variables= {"flow_id":flow_id , "parameters": json_params}
variables = json.dumps(variables).encode('utf-8')
request = requests.post(url, json={'query': query, 'variables': variables}, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Have any guidance on retrieving flow results with this approach?